# Trying to access <p> From multiple websites

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, python-3.x

As the title states, I am trying to get all of the text data from multiple websites. I am able to grab the text data (`<p>`)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: there is not, you have to go to each website individually.

Comment: How did you think that would work?  Magic?  Sorry for being mean, but this is just not a realistic question.  If you want the page, you have to go fetch the page.  And why did you tag Java?

Answer (score 0):

I think beautifulsoup4 is much easier

```
 import requests
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

 url = 'https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/'
 response = requests.get(url)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
 things = soup.find_all('p')
 data = [_.getText() for _ in things]
 print(data)
```

and you can create a loop to access each website and extract all the `<p>` then maybe append to the same list or process it however you want